# Would Oracle be able to figure out the index if apply UPPER to a number column

Tags: oracle, case-insensitive

If we have a column "dob" (varchar2) in table "person"
we can create an index for it i.e. "create index on person(dob)"

If we do queries such as upper(dob), it will ignore the existing index so that
we need create an index like "create index on person(upper(dob))"

However, what if the dob column is of type number?
Can Oracle be clever enough to use index created for person(dob) when the query is upper(dob) or lower(dob) or any operations that has no effect on number columns? 
I know one should never apply the functions to column that if they don't make sense. But let's assume if you had a column as varchar2 but realized that it can be a number only column and didn't change the code that uses this column.
Or if you have some generic logic to apply case insensitivity without checking the column type. 
Or like what Dave said in the comment, if you have existing queries that use UPPER(dob) that can't be changed. 
I know it doesn't at the moment at least for the versions up to 11gr2

Comment: Why on earth would you want to apply `upper()` or `lower()` on a **number**? That does not make any sense whatsoever. And no: an index on `some_column` will never be used for an expression involving changing the value of that column (be it `upper()` or any other function)

Comment: Not commenting on that non-particularly good example, but in the general case, remember that Oracle has both _function based index_ and _virtual columns_. Maybe that's the tools you are looking for ?

Comment: are you saying Oracle would be able to do the check but will never because one should not apply these functions in the first place? I am just curious this is not necessarily how the code is written.

Comment: If you have existing queries that use `UPPER(dob)` that can't be changed, then perhaps you should consider creating a function-based index regardless of the data contained in that column.

Comment: First, don't store dates as VARCHAR2 or NUMBER. The fine folks at Oracle went to a fair degree of time and expense implementing a DATE type - please validate their efforts by making use of it. Further - use of functions in a filter predicate is a Bad Thing. Store the data properly (i.e. convert to upper case at insert time) so you don't have to do this. Triggers can be handy for this sort of thing. Thirdly - if you can't store the data in a standard format, use function-based indexes. Best of luck.

Comment: You're proposing the idea that a lot of code/people are making a lot of errors, like using functions that should not be allowed. It would be interesting to note that ... these errors should not be made. But, to answer the question on indexes: if it is a fact an index doesn't work anymore once you apply a function (any function) onto a column ... well, it doesn't work. - I believe in flexibility, so that end users can be flexible on code usage, but I would not try to adapt code to cover blunt mistakes, like doing Upper or Lower on a number.

Comment: It must be said that a Character column should not contain numbers only. If you come to that conclusion, the architectural design is wrong. Try a TO_NUMBER function on such a "character" column (for ALL records). It should not work.

Comment: If I wanted to keep existing queries intact, but also be able to query `DOB` as a `NUMBER`, I would add a column `DOB_NUMBER` (perhaps even a virtual column if you're using 11g or 12c) with the numerical value of `DOB` and index that column. Then future queries can use it. On the other hand, if I were going to do that, it might be even better to create a `DATE` column instead. But either would be better than modifying the existing data type for that column!

Comment: "It must be said that a Character column should not contain numbers only." - With the caveat that one might use such a column when there are leading zeroes involved (e.g. USPS ZIP codes).

Comment: If the `VARCHAR2` version of `DOB` has the following format: `YYYYMMDD` (which might be useful for `LIKE` queries: `WHERE UPPER(dob) LIKE '1999%')`, then you might do the following to add a virtual column that is a `DATE`: `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD dob_dt GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_DATE(dob, 'YYYYMMDD') );` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d710f/1

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr

The answer is no.

---

This is a relatively strange question. I'm not sure why you'd want to upper-case a number. I'm not sure why you'd be storing the date of birth in a NUMBER column at all!

If you can, store date of birth as a DATE, and don't apply any string manipulation functions.

But, let's try. I've set this up simply as:

```
create table person as
 select level as a
   from dual
connect by level <= 50000;

create index i_person on person (a);
```

Then, on a 11.2.0.3 DB you'll note that upper-casing the number makes a massive difference. A simple SELECT does *exactly* what we expect, and performs an index range scan (because the index is not unique).

```
explain plan for
 select * from person where a = 10045;

Explained.

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 125785894

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |          |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| I_PERSON |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"=10045)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

17 rows selected.
```

However, when applying the `UPPER()` function to the query the filter completely changes and performs a full scan of the table. This is because you are accessing the table via a filter that is not indexed; you'd need to index `UPPER(A)` (in this case) in order for your query to use the index. Note that Oracle is implicitly converting this to a character and then back to a number, and even then the index is not being used.

```
explain plan for
 select * from person where upper(a) = 10045;

Explained.

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1493655343

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |     1 |    13 |    19   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| PERSON |     1 |    13 |    19   (6)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER(UPPER(TO_CHAR("A")))=10045)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

If you can't change the queries (you really should as there's no point upper-casing number columns) and your current queries are too slow (because they're not using the index) then you're going to have to add a functional index on `UPPER(DOB)`. I would just change the queries though...

---

It is theoretically possible that 12c's adaptive execution plans could correct this mid-flight but I haven't managed to make it happen with the following code and looking at the plan in `V$SQL_PLAN` as they were executed:

```
declare
  l_a number;
begin
  for xx in 1 .. 1000 loop
    select a into l_a from person where upper(a) = xx;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

With a larger table and therefore more time for Oracle to act things may change. However, it'd be better to just use the plain index if possible.

Comment: I would bet that Oracle will never be able to use an index because of NLS settings.  With a large enough number, the `TO_CHAR` output will include letters like E, and now `UPPER` and `LOWER` matter.  Is that letter the same, and in the same case, in every language?  There might be some way to sort it out, but I don't know why anybody at Oracle would bother spending the effort.

Comment: I hadn't considered that @Jon, I'm not 100% sure 'cause it's being explicitly converted back into a number in the filter, which implies it's using Oracle's internal representation rather than NLS. I'm definitely with you on the no one bothering front. Just using the correct code solves the problem...